# MEAN App - Updating table after DB Collection update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, express, mean-stack

I 'm trying to keep my table data in sync with the db data.

On Data Change:

```
    $scope.changeStatus = function($event,label,status){
    var target = $event.currentTarget;
    target = $(target).parents('tr').attr('id');
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/update',
        params: {
            trgt : target,
            label : label,
            labelstatus : status,
            searchQuery : $scope.search  
        }
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.events = data;
    })
    .error(
    function(error){
          console.log(error)
    });

}
```

Then:

```
app.post('/update', function(req,res){
    ImportCollection.findOne({ _id : req.query.trgt },function(err,doc){
        doc.label.label = req.query.labelname;
        doc.label.status = req.query.labelstatus;
        doc.save();
});
```

// UNTIL HERE EVERYTHING WORKS JUST FINE

```
if(req.query.searchQuery){
ImportCollection.find({$or:[
    {'localizedData.0.title' : {'$regex': req.query.searchQuery, $options: 'i' }},
    {'licensor.name' : {'$regex': req.query.searchQuery, $options: 'i'}}
    ]})
    .exec(function(err, imports){
        if(err) throw err
        res.json(imports)
        })
    } else{
        ImportCollection.find({},function(err, imports){
            if(err) throw err
            res.json(imports)
            })

    }
});
```

But then the response that should update the table data, is allways one request behind. 
So current Data = Live, I set it to QA and nothing happens. The table is still displaying Live. Once I change it now, lets say to DENIED, the table displays QA. I hope it's clearer now.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the find() block as a callback function to the doc.save() method worked for me:

```
 doc.save(function(err){
          if (err) throw error

          var query = req.query.searchQuery;
          if(query) { 
              ImportCollection.find({$or:[
                     {'localizedData.0.title' : {'$regex': req.query.searchQuery, $options: 'i' }},
                     {'licensor.name' : {'$regex': req.query.searchQuery, $options: 'i'}}
                    ]}).exec(function(err, imports){
                  if(err) throw err
                  res.json(imports)
              });
          } else{
              ImportCollection.find({}).exec(function(err, imports){
                  if(err) throw err
                  res.json(imports)
              });
          }


      });
```